# visual studio 2015 clr form deigner cannot load ui from file

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I'm using visual studio 2015 clr project , with UI form . I've used only editor for create the UI form . But designer cannot load it anymore .
I try to create a new class for the UI , I can't display that neither .

this is `myform.h` file

```
#pragma once

namespace ProvaCLR {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Riepilogo per MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    MyForm(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: aggiungere qui il codice del costruttore.
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Pulire le risorse in uso.
    /// </summary>
    ~MyForm()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::SplitContainer^  splitContainer1;
protected:
private: System::Windows::Forms::SplitContainer^  splitContainer2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ListBox^  listBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox^  groupBox1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip^  menuStrip1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem^  fileToolStripMenuItem;

protected:




private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Variabile di progettazione necessaria.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Metodo necessario per il supporto della finestra di progettazione.            Non modificare
    /// il contenuto del metodo con l'editor di codice.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MyForm::typeid));
        this->splitContainer1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::SplitContainer());
        this->splitContainer2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::SplitContainer());
        this->listBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListBox());
        this->groupBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox());
        this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
        this->menuStrip1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MenuStrip());
        this->fileToolStripMenuItem = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripMenuItem());
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->splitContainer1))->BeginInit();
        this->splitContainer1->Panel1->SuspendLayout();
        this->splitContainer1->Panel2->SuspendLayout();
        this->splitContainer1->SuspendLayout();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->splitContainer2))->BeginInit();
        this->splitContainer2->Panel1->SuspendLayout();
        this->splitContainer2->Panel2->SuspendLayout();
        this->splitContainer2->SuspendLayout();
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
        this->menuStrip1->SuspendLayout();
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // splitContainer1
        // 
        this->splitContainer1->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
        this->splitContainer1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 24);
        this->splitContainer1->Name = L"splitContainer1";
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel1
        // 
        this->splitContainer1->Panel1->Controls->Add(this->splitContainer2);
        // 
        // splitContainer1.Panel2
        // 
        this->splitContainer1->Panel2->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
        this->splitContainer1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(854, 377);
        this->splitContainer1->SplitterDistance = 143;
        this->splitContainer1->TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // splitContainer2
        // 
        this->splitContainer2->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
        this->splitContainer2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
        this->splitContainer2->Name = L"splitContainer2";
        this->splitContainer2->Orientation = System::Windows::Forms::Orientation::Horizontal;
        // 
        // splitContainer2.Panel1
        // 
        this->splitContainer2->Panel1->Controls->Add(this->listBox1);
        // 
        // splitContainer2.Panel2
        // 
        this->splitContainer2->Panel2->Controls->Add(this->groupBox1);
        this->splitContainer2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(143, 377);
        this->splitContainer2->SplitterDistance = 185;
        this->splitContainer2->TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // listBox1
        // 
        this->listBox1->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
        this->listBox1->FormattingEnabled = true;
        this->listBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
        this->listBox1->Name = L"listBox1";
        this->listBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(143, 185);
        this->listBox1->TabIndex = 0;

        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this->groupBox1->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
        this->groupBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
        this->groupBox1->Name = L"groupBox1";
        this->groupBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(143, 188);
        this->groupBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->groupBox1->TabStop = false;
        this->groupBox1->Text = L"groupBox1";
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this->pictureBox1->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
        this->pictureBox1->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"pictureBox1.Image")));
        this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
        this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
        this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(707, 377);
        this->pictureBox1->SizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::PictureBoxSizeMode::Zoom;
        this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
        // 
        // menuStrip1
        // 
        this->menuStrip1->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Windows::Forms::ToolStripItem^  >(1) { this->fileToolStripMenuItem });
        this->menuStrip1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(0, 0);
        this->menuStrip1->Name = L"menuStrip1";
        this->menuStrip1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(854, 24);
        this->menuStrip1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->menuStrip1->Text = L"menuStrip1";
        // 
        // fileToolStripMenuItem
        // 
        this->fileToolStripMenuItem->Name = L"fileToolStripMenuItem";
        this->fileToolStripMenuItem->Size = System::Drawing::Size(37, 20);
        this->fileToolStripMenuItem->Text = L"File";
        // 
        // MyForm
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(854, 401);
        this->Controls->Add(this->splitContainer1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->menuStrip1);
        this->MainMenuStrip = this->menuStrip1;
        this->Name = L"MyForm";
        this->Text = L"LvEditorV2";
        this->splitContainer1->Panel1->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->splitContainer1->Panel2->ResumeLayout(false);
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->splitContainer1))->EndInit();
        this->splitContainer1->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->splitContainer2->Panel1->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->splitContainer2->Panel2->ResumeLayout(false);
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->splitContainer2))->EndInit();
        this->splitContainer2->ResumeLayout(false);
        (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
        this->menuStrip1->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->menuStrip1->PerformLayout();
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }

 #pragma endregion

   };

 }
```

this is myform.cpp

```
 #include "MyForm.h"
 #include "stdio.h"
 using namespace ProvaCLR;
 using namespace System;
 using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

 void  WinMain()
    {
        Application::EnableVisualStyles();
        Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        MyForm form;
        Application::Run(%form);


    }
```

i get this view when i want to see form in designer

[image: I get this view when I want to see form in designer]

and even if I create a new UI form with the class editor , I cannot see that with designer.
Anyone know how I can fix this problem ?

Comment: Change the VS language to English and take the screenshot again. You might even keep it that way.

Comment: don't know why but now it works and i've only change the color of the theme from dark to blue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project Properties --> Linker --> Advanced and You will see the first component named "Entry Point:". Type in "WinMain" which is your main start of the application in the .cpp file. Build and error should be fixed.